# Create single JS including SourceMaps from Angular 9

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

We have a setup where the final artefact of an Angular project is a single JS file. The current process invokes the standard ng build, followed by a

```
nodecat -- dist/tmp/zone-js-dist-zone.js dist/tmp/runtime.js dist/tmp/polyfills.js dist/tmp/main.js > dist/out/all-in-one.js
```

So far, the build has been configured with

```
"sourceMap": false,
```

and custom-webpack

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
     jsonpFunction: 'webpackJsonpMyApp',
    library: 'myApp'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'VERSION': JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime())
    })
  ]
};
```

and that has worked fine. Now we want to enable sourceMaps (for DEV). The sourceMap comments are appended to the individual JS files (as expected), but the `nodecat` command results in an invalid "all-in-one.js" due to these comments.

What is the "right" way to produce a single JS file including sourceMaps? (I think I'm really just missing the right pointer of a lmgtfy)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few SO posts out there with similar issues, none of them with a satisfactory answer. The fundamental issue is that Angular CLI creates source maps per JS file, ie. 1 for main.js, 1 for polyfill.js, 1 for runtime.js etc. As source maps point to file positions, the ensuing concat invalidates all pointers (except for the first file).

Things we've looked into:

### combine-source-map

https://www.npmjs.com/package/combine-source-map looks interesting. I was unable to find a description of how to integrate this with an Angular build, however, and eventually gave up.

### Append sourceMapURL manually

We could (probably, didn't try it out) append the necessary source map references at the bottom of the all-in-one.js, while making sure main.js is at the beginning of the file. Something like

```
nodecat -- dist/tmp/main.js ..all other js files.. src/foobar/sourceMapURLs.js > dist/out/all-in-one.js
```

and sourceMapURLs.js containing only

```
//# sourceMappingURL=our-sourcemap.js.map
```

This should provide a source map for main.js. Pro is that we still have only the one all-in-one.js; con is that source map URL really only covers part of all-in-one.js, and that the nodecat command is not configurable by the CLI "sourceMap" configuration.

### Load and map main.js separately

This is what we ended up implementing, and I understand this doesn't really answer the question above. Maybe it still helps someone.

1. Configure webpack to only generate a source map for main.js
2. Remove main.js from the nodecat command
3. In the loading HTML, load both main.js and all-in-one.js (the latter now holding zone-js-dist-zone.js, runtime.js and polyfills.js)

SourceMapDevToolPlugin config

```
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  filename: '[name].js.map',
  include: ['main.js']
});
```